# Deploy a specific directory to npm with Travis-CI

Tags: npm, travis-ci

I want to deploy the `dist` folder after success. But instead, it keeps deploying the whole repository.

What I want to achieve is the same effect with:

```
npm publish dist
```

Here is the related part from my `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: sa.alemdar@hotmail.com
  api_key:
    secure: MyApiKey
  skip_cleanup: true
  file_glob: true
  file: "dist/**/*"
  on:
    tags: true
    repo: salemdar/angular2-cookie
```

Answer (score 17):

The solution is to use before_deploy script and go to your folder.

Just make sure you have include your package.json in your folder and skip_cleanup option to true.

There is a fonctional solution:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '5'
  - '4'
after_success:
  - npm run build #make a dist folder
before_deploy:
  - cd dist
deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: email@gmail.com
  skip_cleanup: true
  api_key:
    secure: ##your_secure_key
  on:
    branch: master
    tags: true
    repo: loveindent/stateful-api-mock-server
```

Comment: I was trying to do this, but travis doesn't deploy the dist folder as it is in my gitnore. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Might be a good idea to do `cd ..` in after_deploy to reset to initial state. Especially usefull if you have coverage running in after_scripts. Lost some time on it.